# Access contact list to use e-mail address?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-mobile, compact-framework

i have no idea of how to access the contact list of the windows mobile programmatically to use the email addresses.

i want to show the the email of contact list only and when user selects one of them email value is retrieved in a string .

please help me.

regards,
Madhup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the windows mobile SDK, you can reference in:

Microsoft.WindowsMobile.PocketOutlook

Then in your code, add in

```
using Microsoft.WindowsMobile.PocketOutlook;
```

Then you can use that to get contacts using ContactCollection

Comment: hey Nils thanks for the reply. but i don't want to use pocket outlook i want to access the contact list normally,because if the pocket outlook is not configured in a device then what a user will do?

Comment: There is no other way but POOM.  And email doesn't have to be configured to get to the Contacts list.

Comment: Yes, this is the way to do it - if you've got contacts on your winmobile phone, regardless of whether you've set up email on your phone, then they will appear in the ContactCollection. On Winmobile pocketoutlook is the store for phone contacts as well.

Comment: Don't confuse Pocket Outlook (the collective name for the built in Contacts, Messaging and Calendar applications etc) and connectivity to a server based Exchange account.

Using POOM (The Pocket Outlook Object Model) is the only practical way to interact with PIM type data held within the built in applications.